# Where is Harbor Club building in Sandals Ochi?

Tags: jamaica

[image]The map: https://www.sandals.com/ochi/maps/

Is the Harbor Club building synonymous with another building in the map?

I am trying to confirm accommodations location and appreciate any references that confirms a response.

Comment: Did you click on Accommodation? Do that, hover and one of the red dots says Harbor Club....

Comment: @Giorgio  Thank you.   If you promote your response to an answer, it can be rewarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Sandals Ochi](https://www.sandals.com/ochi/maps/) resort map is interactive: if you click on an option at the top of the image, hover over a corresponding colored dot that appears, it displays the name of the amenity (Accommodations, Pools & Whirlpools, Activities, Land & Water Sports, Restaurants & Bars, Shops & Retail, Misc.).